# x,y spatial indexes per batch for an image in pytorch

Tags: pytorch

I'm trying to learn how to solve a very basic problem in the general case, so I have it readily available for my intuitive toolbox of tensor processing.

### Specific

I would like a way so that given a mask float image M: B, H, W (batch, height, width) produce a `LongTensor` image M': B, H, W, 2 so that the last two dimensions correspond to the row and col indices of M.

I guess you can achieve this through some sort of arange functionality but not sure how to do.
E.g. I was thinking something like:

```
torch.cat([
    torch.arange(H).unsqueeze(0).unsqueeze(-1).expand(B, H, W).unsqueeze(-1), 
    torch.arange(W).unsqueeze(0).unsqueeze(0).expand(B, H, W).unsqueeze(-1)
], dim=-1)
```

### General

A bit harder version of this problem is to do the same but return to arrays M: B, K, 2 elements that follow a certain condition.

I guess the last is like a batched version of torch.nonzero but not sure how to do it.

### Why?

Using this trick you can compute the "center of a mask".

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

An alternative to your approach is to use the builtin [`torch.meshgrid`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.meshgrid.html) which essentially constructs an n-dimensional grid given n sequences of indices. Coupled with [`torch.stack`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.stack.html), you can get the desired result:

```
torch.stack(torch.meshgrid(torch.arange(H), torch.arange(W)), dim=-1)
```

Although in your 2-dimensional case this meshgrid indeed comes down to the same as you wrote:

```
torch.cat((torch.arange(H)[None,:,None,None].expand(B,H,W,1),
           torch.arange(W)[None,None,:,None].expand(B,H,W,1)), dim=-1)
```

---

However, concerning your general case, you won't be able to perform batch-condition checks.

For the more general question, you are looking to construct `M'` from a condition based on the values of `M`, correct? For instance `M==2`, would make `M'` only contain 2d coordinates of points in `M` which are equal to `2`.

If I understand correctly what you meant by *"center of mask"*. The answer is you won't be able to find it this way. The reason why is that *condition masking* doesn't retain tensor dimensionality, it reduces it (*i.e.* flattens it) because masking produces non-homogenous results which can't be represented in a batch-wise manner.